Showing bin upper/lower bound for discrete legend for raster in QGIS
I want to have binned coloring/legend for my raster data.  I can get to show only the upper bound of the bin. Is there a way to show the legend with upper/lower bound, like this?
['< 0', '0 - 0.05', ... , '0.25 - 0.3']


Consulted GhatGPT, and told that i can export style, hand edit XML, then import back.  Maybe that's what i would do unless there is simpler way.  I was hoping an one button-click solution

Change your interpolation to "Discrete". E.g:


Thanks!!  Exactly the option i was looking for!
